# AsyncTask Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)

Tags: android, image, url, android-asynctask, user-permissions

I am trying use AsyncTask to extract an image over the internet and display on the RecyclerViewer but I am getting the following error message, which's captured from my Exception in my doInBackground from my RecyclerViewAdapter class:

```
08-02 00:11:25.608: E/ImageDownload(5753): Download failed: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
```

See full version of AsyncTask sub-class below:

```
 class GetImageFromNet extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder personViewHolder;
private String url = "http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BNDMyODU3ODk3Ml5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwNDc1ODkwNjE@._V1_SX300.jpg";

 public GetImageFromNet(RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder personViewHolder){
     this.personViewHolder = personViewHolder;
 }
 protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
    try {
        InputStream in = new java.net.URL(url).openStream();
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        return bitmap;
        //NOTE:  it is not thread-safe to set the ImageView from inside this method.  It must be done in onPostExecute()
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ImageDownload", "Download failed: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = null;
    }
    personViewHolder.personPhoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}
```

I have no idea why I am getting above error since I have already added the following permission access in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />


        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help!

Comment: it seems that it is server issue which u need to credential to download images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move your `<uses-permission>` elements to be immediate children of `<manifest>`, above your `<application>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Update your manifest as:-

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.xxx" >
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```